# @Html.Dropdownlist list isn't saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the below example I'm trying to save the Id from the Asp.Net Identity, "aspnetusers" table "Id" column into my "Application" table. The dropdownlist of "fullname" populates, but is not saving to my "application" table when I submit an application. I need the "Id" from the aspnetusers table to be saved to my "application" table after submitting the application. Help would be greatly appreciated!

***Controller:***

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.FullNameList = new SelectList(db.Users,"Id","FullName");
    return View();
}

// POST: Applications/Create
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Id,FullName, FirstName,MiddleInitial,LastName,")]   Application application)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.FullNameList = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName", application.ApplicationUser);
        db.Applications.Add(application);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Thanks");
    }
}
```

***View:***

```
<p>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FullName, (SelectList)ViewBag.FullNameList, "Select Loan Officer")
</p>
```

***Model:***

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Middle Initial")]
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual string FullName {get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many things wrong:

1. Your post action accepts `Application`, which doesn't have a `FullName` property.
2. Even if it did, your `Bind` attribute doesn't included it.
3. You can't have a `ViewBag` member holding your select list with the same name as the field you're trying to post. Change it to something like `ViewBag.FullNameChoices`.
4. The posted value would be the `Id` of the "loan officer" user and you're doing nothing with it. If you actually had a foreign key property, you could post directly to that, but instead you're just relying on EF to create an implicit property which you have no access to. In your post action, you would need to look up the user with that `Id` from the database and then set your `ApplicationUser` property to that.
5. While not technically *wrong*, having a property that represents the "loan officer" for an application call `ApplicationUser` is not intuitive. You should change it to something like `LoanOfficer`. Also, it looks like your assuming that all users for all time will also be "loan officers", you should probably plan some flexibility by creating a subclass of `ApplicationUser` for a loan officer or use roles to assign that status.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your feedback.  I've updated my code to reflect the changes you suggested in steps 1-3.  In my case for steps 4 and 5, I am using the ASP.NET Identity "aspnetusers" table for the loan officer full name and ID.  My goal is that when a user registers, his/her full name is populated in the dropdown list on the application home page.  This part is working, but the Id, and FullName properties are still not being saved to the application.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You added a `FullName` property and included it in the bind, but then you went and changed your field name to `FullNameList`, so you're still violating point 3 and now your posting `FullNameList` which is not a property on `Application` or included in the bind (points 1 and 2). Use `Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FullName, (SelectList)ViewBag.FullNameList, "Select Loan Officer")`

Comment: Interestingly, now the "FullName" in my application table is being populated with a hashed value and the ApplicationUser_Id that was populated as my foreign key is still blank.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, the posted value is the id of the user, not the full name that was displayed in the drop down. You must take this value and use it to look up the associated user from the database and set ApplicationUser to that manually on your entity.

Comment: Is it possible to post the full name from the dropdown into my application table? The reason I want to do this is because I'd like to have the user log in automatically and be shown a list of his/her applications via a query by fullname that matches the registered user that is logged in.

Comment: I think I understand now.  I need to capture the Id of whoever is logged in and then just query the applications with that Id. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to add an `[HttpPost]`?

Also, your `DropDownList` might be:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FullName", ViewBag.FullName, "Select Loan Officer")
```